# How to dynamically change Toolbar from activity inside ViewPager (TabLayout)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I'm struggling with Toolbar Button and ViewPager with TabLayout inside my app. I have multiple Toolbar Buttons, that I want to change dynamically (Add or remove icon/button on Toolbar, and set different onClickListener for each Fragment) inside Fragment loaded inside TabLayout. The main problem here is that ViewPager load 2 fragments in a row in order to provide the scroll animation, but there is no method in order to know if the fragment is really displayed or not... (Except setUserVisibleHint, but this method is deprecated, and doesn't seems to be really reliable), so does someone have a solution in order for my app to run great with that behaviour? (Changing dynamically the icon on my Toolbar inside the Fragment)

Thanks!

Comment: You can try to use tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener();

Comment: Thanks! But can I set this property directly inside my Fragment? Because I assign onClickListener to my button inside my Fragment, so with this method I can easily show or hide button but I can't set method from inside my Fragment :/

Comment: Yes you can set the listener everywhere

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you have a little architecture to set that? Because I have my main activity which set up VIewPager and TabLayout but I don't see how to set your listener directly inside my Fragments :/ I also already have this listener inside my mainactivity viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener I think it's quite similar to yours, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the logic inside the onResume of your Fragment. onResume basically means that this fragment is visible for the user. This should solve your problem. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, because adjacent Fragment cycle is called on creation. So when my tab 1 is loaded, TabLayout load tab 2 (without movement on the app), so onResume is called 2 times, once for my first tab and once for my second

Comment: onResume on the second fragment will only be triggered if you switch tab to that fragment. @ExPl0siF